# System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses throws 'No such host is known' when calling in a loop

Tags: c#, .net-core

The case is the following: if I call Dns.GetHostAddresses(host) once, it works, it returns me correct IP.

If I do

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
}
```

it throws SockedException with the above message pretty quickly. Does anybody know why?

-- Edit

I'm getting 11001 error code, this is .NET Core 3.1 on Win 10.
The host which I'm trying to resolve is my Ubuntu VM running on a Hyper-V on the same Win 10.

Comment: This error means the host failed to resolve. Try check the ErrorCode property of the thrown SocketException.

Comment: For context it would be interesting which OS this is on (mac, linux, windows) and which .NET Core / .NET version. The reasons could be multiple from framework bugs to DNS servers rate-limiting your requests.

Comment: I added some more info. I'm also thinking about some rate-limiting, but not quite sure